# How to store SHA1 output to a file using C

Tags: c, hash, sha1

I have computed the `SHA1` for a piece of data and I need to store it into a file to be read by another person later. The `SHA1` gives the output as `190 bit's`, but I can't store as bits into a file, `fputc()` function does it characters which means bytes.

So I want to either store it as bytes into the file or as its `hexadecimal` representation (preferably). In `C`, so far I can only get it to print the hash to the terminal as the hexadecimal representation (using a way I found in another question posted in this site), but I can't figure out how to store it to a file properly.

Please help!

Comment: Curious; I thought SHA1 gave 160 bits; SHA2 can yield 192, 256, 384 or 512 bits, and SHA3 likewise.

Comment: SHA1 is 160 bit which is 20 bytes. There might be a problem with the SHA1 implementation you used.

Comment: The library probably has code to generate or convert the SHA1 checksum to the appropriate hexadecimal representation (40 hex digits for a 160-bit checksum, for example).

Comment: I am using openssl as instructed by lecturer, which gives the unsigned char *SHA1(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n,
                  unsigned char *md); function to use. and the output gives 160bits as you corrected me sorry.

Comment: if I use the terminal to compute with SHA1 openssl the output is shown in hexadecimal straight away, but when using the function in code, and then printf it, the terminal shows the gibberish characters as opposed to hex. I want to store to a file in hex representation to use it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write the SHA1 digest as binary digest in the file,  you can use:

```
fwrite ( &sha1_digest, sizeof(sha1_digest), 1, stream );
```

Where `stream` is a FILE* opened in binary mode.

If you want to save it as hexadecimal string,  you can do a loop :

```
char *p=(void*)&sha1_digest; 
int i=sizeof(sha1_digest); 
while (i--) 
    fprintf (stream, "%02x",*p++);
```

where tream is a FILE* opened in text or binary mode

I assumed that `sha1_digest` was a structure.  If it's an array, you don't need the `&` and if the array is not fixed size, then you must provide the size of the digest (because in this case, s`izeof()` would return the sizeof a pointer isntead of the array.)

You are certainly aware, but [SHA1 is no longer considered as a safe hash](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html), if your use is somewhat related to security.

Comment: it is just for exercise purposes, Say: Alice computes the SHA1 of a password and stores it in the file which she sends to Bob, who has the same password, and he generates a SHA1 on his password, then compares it to the SHA1 digest of Alice, they need to match as the same password is hashed with SHA1, but currently my comparison fails. I did before, fprintf(fp, "%s\n", SHA1_digest); but realised the format was a string but the digest is in bits so when I compared with Bob's digest, the comparison didn't show they are the same. That's my problem and I can't figure out how to do it now..

Answer (score 1):

i used the following code for generating sha1 hash of text stored in message.txt file(text is: hello how are you).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024*16

void do_fp(FILE *f);
void pt(unsigned char *md);
#ifndef _OSD_POSIX
int read(int, void *, unsigned int);
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, err = 0;
    FILE *IN,*fp;

    if (argc == 1) {
      do_fp(stdin);
    }
 else {
printf("hi");        
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            IN = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if (IN == NULL) {
                perror(argv[i]);
                err++;
                continue;
            }
            printf("SHA1(%s)= ", argv[i]);
            do_fp(IN);
            fclose(IN);
        }
    }
    exit(err);
}

void do_fp(FILE *f)
{
    SHA_CTX c;
    unsigned char md[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    int fd;
    int i;
    unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    fd = fileno(f);
    SHA1_Init(&c);
    for (;;) {
        i = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZE);
        if (i <= 0)
            break;
        SHA1_Update(&c, buf, (unsigned long)i);
    }
    SHA1_Final(&(md[0]), &c);
    fp = fopen("file.txt","wb");

   char *p=(void*)md; 
   i=SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; 
   while (i--) 
   fprintf (fp, "%02x",*p++);
 pt(md);
}

void pt(unsigned char *md)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        printf("%02x", md[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

i got followng as output. SHA1(message.txt)= 46e7b8310aa4d03b57e11022166d37beedf36537 however hash stored in file.txt is as follows. 46ffffffe7ffffffb8310affffffa4ffffffd03b57ffffffe11022166d37ffffffbeffffffedfffffff36537 please provide necessary guidance to achieve correct hash in file.txt. thank you in advance.
```